# Introducing a menu by clicking the mode-line lighter

Tags: keymap, menus

I have a menu defined in `tika-menuitm-kymap` which I want to incorporate in the mode line of the minor mode.  How can I set up the minor mode properties so that the menu shows up in the `mode-line` ?

My attempt at defining the minor mode with

```
(define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
  "Enhances visibility of heading levels and text emphasis."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Tika")
```

did not result in the menu showing up.

```
(defvar tika-menuitm-kymap
  (let ((menuitm-kymap (make-sparse-keymap)))

    (define-key menuitm-kymap [hide]
                (cons "Hide" (make-sparse-keymap "Hide")))

    (define-key menuitm-kymap [hide body]
                '(menu-item "Hide Body" outline-hide-body
                            :help "Hide bodies, visible headings"))
    menuitm-kymap))

;;--------

(defvar tika-menubar-kymap

  (let ((menubar-kymap (make-sparse-keymap)))

    (define-key menubar-kymap [tika]
      (cons "Outl"
            (nconc (make-sparse-keymap "Outl Menu")

                   (apply #'append
                          (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (consp x) (cdr x)))
                                  tika-menuitm-kymap)))))

    menubar-kymap))
```

Comment: For one thing, `define-key` expects `(kbd "H-b")`, not `"H-b"`. You really need to consult the doc...

Comment: Even if I do that I get `(error "Uneven number of key/definition pairs")`.

Comment: Have also removed it completely leaving just `:suppress "<menu-bar>"` and `:name tika-menubar-kmap`.  The menu still does not get displayed.

Comment: No, you havent edited the question to remove the extraneous problem(s). Reduce your question to what you really want to ask, instead of trying to discuss things in comments.

Comment: I do not know what I am doing wrong, and thus what are the extraneous things to leave out.  I basically have a menu and definition of key sequences.  Have just kept one menu item if that helps.

Comment: Seems that you dont know the ELisp format style recommended by the manual. Please search for it.

Comment: We are not here to talk about style but to get things working,

Comment: Bisect your code to find the problem, then remove what's irrelevant. Or set `debug-on-error` to `t`, to find the problematic key binding. Remove the part of your question that talks about the mode line, because it's not in the code. Etc. IOW, reduce your question to just the *problematic* code. Some reflection might then point you in the right direction. If you post extraneous stuff it's maybe less likely that others will help you, and it's almost certainly less likely that you'll help yourself as much as you could. Narrow the search space. Just a suggestion.

Comment: debug-on-error does not give me the source of the problem.  Actually it does not give me a backtrace of any errors.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the question you're trying to ask is "how do I add items to the default clickable menu made available by emacs in the modeline when one clicks on the lighter of a minor mode" ? If so, please edit your question to make it clear that this is the one and only question you are asking.

Comment: One clarifying question: do you want this menu to show up in emacs' GUI menu bar or not?

Comment: Correct, I am trying to have a clickable menu similar to `outline-minor-mode`.  It would be good  to have the menu also show up in the Emacs GUI Menu Bar, but perhaps that can be a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the question is "how do I add items to the default clickable menu made available by emacs in the modeline when one clicks on the lighter of a minor mode".

In this particular case, the answer is actually already available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617894/234025

The *very short answer* here is "there is a macro called `easy-menu-define` and you should just open the help menu for it, because the rest of it depends on what you want to do.
This being said, for the sake of example, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "documentation here"
  nil
 " Foo")

(defun foo-do-it ()
  (interactive)
  (message "hi"))

(easy-menu-define foo-mode-menu foo-mode-map
  "documentation"
  '("Foo"
    ["say hi"] foo-do-it t]))
```

Everything unexplained here is explainable through emacs' documentation, specifically `define-minor-mode` and `easy-menu-define`.

Play around and you'll get both what you need and a deeper understanding of the emacs subsystems at play :)

Comment: How do I construct `tika-mode-map` for this case ?  I get much discussion but at all times things are untested and unworking in their details because of missing declarations.

Comment: Am I answering the correct question?

Comment: You are answering the use of easy menu.  But I was not using easy menu.  I was using the approach found in `outline-minor-mode`,

Comment: Still, I would be interested to see the use of an easy-menu on a toy minor-mode.  Code that fails in its intention by requirements to play with it is not very helpful.

Comment: The problem for me has been in the definition of the keymap.

Comment: @Dilna you need to ask exactly the question that you want the answer to. Does this mean the question is "I want to implement a menu that shows up when a user clicks on the lighter for a minor mode exactly the way outline-minor-mode implements its menu" ?

Comment: @Dilna in addition, this answer was edited to show a working solution using easy-menu-define on a toy minor mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147147/discussion-between-trevoke-and-dilna).